# Meteor : insert failed method not found error

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor

i have tried a blog with the meteor framework, while inserting the value it showing like insert failed and method not found error, i am suffering from 2 hours please correct the code and make this work, thanks in advance

this a javascript file:

```
Testing = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

 Template.postForm.events({
    "submit .post-form": function (event) {

  // Prevent default browser form submit
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get value from form element
  var title = $('#title').val();
  var description = $('#description').val();


  // Insert a task into the collection
  Testing.insert({
    title: title,
    description: description
   // current time
  });

  // Clear form
}
  });
}
```

the html file is :

```
<template name="postForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form role="form" class="post-form" id="submit">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                        title
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">
                        description
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="exampleInputFile">
                        File input
                    </label>
                    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" />
                    <p class="help-block">
                        Example block-level help text here.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and i have tried both

```
Testing = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
```

and

```
Testing = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the solution from my friend in facebook

we need to put

```
Testing = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
```

inside the lib folder

Comment: Some prefer to name this "both" instead of "lib" as that makes its purpose/function clearer.

Comment: inside the lib folder? what does it mean? please make your answer clear.. in which file? and where should you add this line?

Comment: Putting new Mongo.Collection('posts') in my server startup code worked out for me